# Ebean query operator "Fetch" isn't working when I use more than one relationship path

Tags: java, orm, ebean

It is my understanding that when I use `fetch` when querying an object, Ebean will try to fetch the relationship using a join.

e.g.

```
Ebean.find(ProjectRequest.class)
                    .fetch("attachments")
                    .findList();
```

**This works as expected when trying to fetch one relationship.**

But when I try to `fetch` more than one relation it doesn't query any of the relationships with a join and fetches all the relationships with a separate query.

e.g.

```
Ebean.find(ProjectRequest.class)
                    .fetch("projectConstructionCosts")
                    .fetch("attachments")
                    .fetch("projectRequestComments")
                    .fetch("additionalContacts")
                    .where()
                    .in("project_status", projectStatusValues)
                    .findList();
```

I should be able to do this based on the code examples in this documentation page. 
https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidoc/10/io/ebean/FetchConfig.html

Answer (score 1):

I use "*" for fetchProperties and work for me

```
Ebean.find(ProjectRequest.class)
                .fetch("projectConstructionCosts", "*")
                .fetch("attachments", "*")
                .fetch("projectRequestComments", "*")
                .fetch("additionalContacts", "*")
                .where()
                .in("project_status", projectStatusValues)
                .findList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't query any of the relationships with a join and fetches all the relationships with a separate query

The reason Ebean does not use a SQL join but instead creates additional separate queries to load those associations is because the relationships are `ToMany` relationships and Ebean will never generate SQL Cartesian product (because it is deemed too risky / expensive).

That is, Ebean will only allow 1 of the `ToMany` relationships to be included in the "root query" (in order to avoid sql cartiesian product) and the other relationships are then loaded as "secondary queries".

Additionally note that if the query includes a `max rows` limit then Ebean will honor this in generated SQL. In this case Ebean can't include a SQL join to a `ToMany` and that would become a "secondary query" (not part of the root SQL query).

Reference: https://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/query/fetch